# React Router v6 - component flashing/flickering when changing page at the first time load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In clientspace component, I have a navigation which use  for routing page. But when my page always flickers when I first load it. Anyone can give me some advice?

App.tsx

```
    const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<AuthPage />} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/" element={<ClientSpacePage />}>
                <Route path="/A" element={<APage />} />
                <Route path="/B" element={<BPage />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<p>Path not resolved</p>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

**clientSpace.component.tsx**

```
function ClientSpacePage() {

  return (

        <div className="app">
          <Navigation />
          <main className="content">
            <Outlet />
          </main>
        </div>
  );
}

export default ClientSpacePage;
```

I see many people having the same problem as me on the stackoverflow. But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Why do you have your `"/A"` and `"/B"` wrapped inside the Home Page `"/"`? Not sure if that could be the fix what happens if you have the `"/"` route in a self-close bracket?

Comment: "/A" and "/B" are a child routes of "/". If the "/" route in a self-close bracket. I will lost the <Navigation /> when I am on the component A and B 
 
`<Route path="/" element={<ClientSpacePage />} />
<Route path="/A" element={<APage />} />
<Route path="/B" element={<BPage />} />`

Comment: You can move the `Navigation` inside `PrivateRoutes`? Other than that, it's highly unlikely that that is the cause of the *flickering* you are seeing; you probably have some authentication condition that takes some time, I'll just guess it's the `Navigation` navigating the User to `/login` then your `AuthPage` re-navigates the User back to the `PrivateRoutes`. You should provide more code like the `Navigation` and `AuthPage` components.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I found the problem, it's not because react-router-v6. The problem comes from `useTranslation (react-i18next)`. It is used in components A and B. When I remove it from theses components, I don't see flashing anymore.